# I want to send a confirmation mail on event of submit button in webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, rules

I have a webform and a E-mail field in it Is it possible to have a confirmation mailed out to the person registering? (as in, is it possible to have the functionality also worked in?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Webform settings, click on the E-mail settings tab. Then make sure you select the radio button with "Component value", select "Email", then add this component. In the next page configure the fields as you want. You also have there a template area, where you can select a custom template and add there whatever you want. You can also use tokens.

Notice that I use the SMTP Module, and I haven't tried without it, so i'm not entirely sure it will work. Best of luck!

Answer (score 9):

The webform module comes with an option to send e-mails after submission. Check the webform e-mail tab when you are editing a webform

Comment: I have tried that but its not working as it giving a massage form submitted but can't send mail

Comment: could you verify that other emails are send from drupal. Because that should work out of the box

Comment: Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists. This kind of massage is been display

Comment: That sounds more likely that your server and/drupal aren't configured right for sending e-mails

Comment: it was the issue with SMTP and after fixing that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal core

Drupal core modules comes with the function to send email confirmation for when a user registers. It's not necessary to use a webform for this.

Webform

With the module [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) you can add conditions to your webform, each can then trigger an action. There are a lot of options for posible action, since the module [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) provides most of them. There you can check for the email notification you need.

[image: Rules, email confirmation]